# Are we a part of community or we just want self reputation and badges?

Tags: discussion

With no reason my answer has been [downvoted once in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/609074/fastest-easiest-way-to-install-any-linux-distro-ubuntu-mint-whaever-on-windo/)

The above post has been down voted without any sound reason. It is strange!

Even after editing answers and giving proper reasoning, the down votes are not removed. What sort sportsmanship is it?

Are we not a part of a community or we just want to increase our badges and reputation and hope for decrease in reputation of others!

Comment: Probably all of us get downvotes every now and then. Why would you care even the slightest bit after 15 upvotes?

Answer (score -4):

Someone is jealous. Ask Ubuntu cannot help it.